# Storing data which is automatically cleared on device reboot

Tags: android, android-storage

I am trying to find out if there is a way to store data on Android that is automatically cleared when a user reboots the device. For e.g. the data stored in `SharedPreferences` lives through device reboots. I want to store data that is automatically cleared when user reboots the device. The various ways that Android provides to store data that I found are

1. Internal storage
2. External storage
3. SharedPreferences
4. SQLite database

Even the cache files are not guaranteed to be cleared on device reboots. Please answer if you know how could this be achieved.

Comment: what about a broadcastreceiver that does it for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_SHUTDOWN.
go to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) for detail.
and clear data programmaticaly in case of sharedPreference and sqlLite database

Answer (score 3):

Store the data as you wish. Clear the data after the reboot.

Use BootCompleted `BroadcastReceiver` to clear your data after the restart.

```
        <receiver android:name="YourReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Although what you have suggested is correct, I wanted to use this approach on devices such as Xiaomi where the boot event receiver is not called unless the app is added to Autostart apps. ACTION_SHUTDOWN works on that device also.